# How to Change Textbox name before Submit in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change a textbox name before form submit

My text box:

```
<input type="text" name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" />
```

I make this function for java script:

```
function abc()
{
    document.getElementById('txtUserName').name="ID_USERNAME"
    document.loginform.action = "url";
}
```

I tried `document.getElementById('txtUserName').name="ID_USERNAME"` but not working

**Note**: Please Do not use JQuery Function

Comment: **Note!** Java is to Javascript as car is to carpet, both have nothing to do with each other! (Post was tagged `java`)

Comment: Why would you want/need to do this? could you give a bit more information as to what you're trying to achieve, it feels like there should be a simpler solution to this

Comment: i have a login form thats required the some type of user name will post some other url and some of the user post in same url, so the other url has different name of textbox(user name text box)

Comment: `document.loginform` may not work in last firefox versions. Use `document.getElementById('loginform')` instead.

Comment: You code to change the name works fine. What makes you think it doesn't work? http://jsfiddle.net/giddygeek/XvtnZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine. (I filled in a few bits):

See it running here : http://jsfiddle.net/giddygeek/XvtnZ/2/ Run it and inspect the element (in Chrome) or view the source, and check your textbox element.

```
<form id="login_form" action="">
 <input type="text" action="post" name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
function abc()
{
    document.getElementById('txtUserName').name="ID_USERNAME"
    document.getElementById('login_form').action = "the_url";
    //check the values..
//    alert(document.getElementById('txtUserName').name );
//    alert(document.getElementById('login_form').action );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
document.getElementById('txtUserName').setAttribute("name","ID_USERNAME");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would better write the correct name into the input field.
If that for any reason can't be done I would simply do:

```
<form onsubmit="this[0].name='ID_USERNAME';">
    <input type="text" name="txtUserName" id="txtUserName" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```